# Cannot install librdkafka on Mac Monterey

Tags: macos, apache-kafka, homebrew, librdkafka

I'm trying to install librdkafka on Mac Monterey:

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka

It says:

```
brew install librdkafka
```

However, I'm getting compiler errors indicating it's missing. Upon taking a look i was expecting it to install in `/usr/local/lib` but it's not there.

When I do:

```
find . -name "*kafka*"
```

I'm still not finding it (or at least nothing which looks like it).

If I try running brew again I get:

```
Warning: librdkafka 1.8.2 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.8.2, run:
  brew reinstall librdkafka
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Homebrew should be using `/usr/local/Cellar`

```
$ brew install librdkafka
Warning: librdkafka 1.8.2 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.8.2, run:
  brew reinstall librdkafka
$ brew info librdkafka
librdkafka: stable 1.8.2 (bottled), HEAD
Apache Kafka C/C++ library
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka
/usr/local/Cellar/librdkafka/1.8.2 (36 files, 4.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-10-22 at 12:56:59
```

```
$ tree /usr/local/Cellar/librdkafka/1.8.2/lib/
/usr/local/Cellar/librdkafka/1.8.2/lib/
├── librdkafka++.1.dylib
├── librdkafka++.a
├── librdkafka++.dylib -> librdkafka++.1.dylib
├── librdkafka.1.dylib
├── librdkafka.a
├── librdkafka.dylib -> librdkafka.1.dylib
└── pkgconfig
    ├── rdkafka++-static.pc
    ├── rdkafka++.pc
    ├── rdkafka-static.pc
    └── rdkafka.pc

1 directory, 10 files
```

> I'm getting compiler errors indicating it's missing

I suspect these errors say something *else* is missing

Comment: Hi, thanks. for replying. The compiler error was "fatal error: 'librdkafka/rdkafka.h' file not found". I've found librdkafka in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/librdkafka/1.8.2/. Given this compiles fine for my colleagues, I assume my installation has gone to the wrong path?

Comment: Does this mean an environment variable is causing my installations to go to /opt/homebrew/ instead of /usr/local and what would this variable be for me to check?

Comment: Ah, I think it's because I have an M1 processor and Homebrew (Apple) has a different installation path to Homebrew (Intel) but if you could confirm this would explain it?

Comment: That makes sense to me! I don't have access to an M1 Mac to compare against. Maybe using Rosetta terminal would solve things for you? And yes, there's some environment variable for the Homebrew path, but I cannot recall it right now